# Xubuntu 12.04 does not start

Tags: boot-failure

I have installed Xubuntu 12.04 on my old computer recently and it worked fine for several days but now I have a big problem. I was in the process of installing a program and in the same time browsing the internet when the system somehow stopped responding. It crashed (i.e. froze) for a rather long time. I got annoyed (which was really stupid) and restarted but it didn't get to the log in screen. So I pressed the turn on button and held it for a while which turned everything off. Then I turned the computer on again but it didn't get to the log in screen. I restarted a couple of times but with no effect. Apparently Xubuntu is not that robust as Windows. Now I am using the live CD to browse the internet and search for help. Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

Comment: If you feel that "Apparently Xubuntu is not that robust as Windows" it may be better to revert to Windows. It's quite possible that your hardware is better suited to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok boot your computer to login screen and then type as CTRL + ALT + F1

login there with your username and password . Then run this command

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

hope that helps .

Comment: I will try that. What is this command supposed to do?

Comment: I tried that what snow suggested but it didn't work. After restarted I couldn't get to the login screen as before. Nevertheless, I pressed CTRL+ALT+F1 but nothing happened. I have tried that before on Ubuntu but this time it did not produce any result.